# One-to-many Inter Process Communication on Linux

Tags: linux, sockets

I have a 'server' process that produces some logs. I want the user (or some other service) to be able to view that log stream (like `tail -f`), but I don't want to write those logs to the filesystem. Can I do this on Linux?

1. My first attempt was to use UDP, on the loopback interface. The server sends packets to localhost on port 12345, and clients can bind to that port to receive them. Doesn't work. Because only one client can bind to the same socket. Ah! But you might say use SO_REUSE_ADDR, that lets two clients bind to one port, but only one receives the messages.
2. Next up, I tried UDP multicast on the loopback interface. That one didn't get so far, as my kernel doesn't support multicast on the loopback interface. According to `ifconfig`:

   ```
   lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
             inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
             UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
             RX packets:186 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
             TX packets:186 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
             collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
             RX bytes:11904 (11.6 KiB)  TX bytes:11904 (11.6 KiB)
   ```

   Note the lack of `MULTICAST` (or `BROADCAST`, indeed), above.

Does anyone have any ideas? Could I use named pipes, or Unix Domain Sockets to solve this?

I'd like to avoid anything that allows the (unpriviledged) listeners to affect the (privileged) server. I'd rather drop logs than block the server, for example.

I'm doing all this in Python, if that makes any difference at all.

Comment: a question raised at your first paragraph: what's the use of logging if you can only read it realtime? what not put it in a file?

Comment: it basically requires a poll loop(`select`, `poll`, `epoll`) running to connection to client, maintain a list of active clients and send the latest log to them as soon as it's generated. probably it's better to use pipe to pass log from your main server to a helper tcp/udp server via pipe and do the loop there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a look at ZeroMQ. What you're describing is a need to a publisher/subscriber pattern, which is exactly the kind of thing ZeroMQ does really quite elegantly. It has the added advantage of being very flexible on what sort of transport is used underneath; IPC, TCP, etc. That makes putting bits of your program elsewhere on a network quite simple. Using ZeroMQ you will end up with very simple source code, the complexity all being hidden inside the zmq library. You could start by taking a look at this part of the [guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Getting-the-Message-Out)

You could also consider NanoMSG (the up and coming ZeroMQ-done-better), though I'm not sure that's got Python bindings as yet.

Comment: This looks like a good solution. I had always incorrectly thought that ZeroMQ used a broker process! And the PUB socket type won't block. I will investigate further...

Comment: @joerick, yep, broker-less is good. For the record, Data Distribution Service is also broker-less. RabbitMQ has a broker, one wonders what happens when that breaks. In ZeroMQ there are threads running in the background doing all the work, but the net result is that none of them are critical to the operation of the whole system. One breaks, everything else carries on, hopefully. Restart the broken one, everything carries on as normal.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two generic approaches.

1) Using POSIX shared memory objects.

See the shm_open(3) manual page for more information.

Your application would create a shared memory object, where it will write its log messages, and any client application can open a shared memory object, and read it. Although the POSIX shared memory API looks like a filesystem-based API, it's not.

Now, bear in mind, that you're going to get just a chunk of memory, of some size that you request. You'll have to figure out how your application will structure, and manage this chunk of memory in some meaningful way that your client applications can parse, and poll for changed contents.

2)

Your application bears the burden of opening and listening on a localhost socket, or a filesystem domain socket, that any client can connect to, and your application will simply write its log messages to every client connection that currently exists.

This is a bit tricky to get right. Your application will need to be able to constantly accept new connections from clients, whenever they come in, write messages to all concurrent connections, detect when some client gets stuck, does not read from its end of the socket, hence making the local sockets internal buffers full, so a blocking write would block and hang the main application; hence all writes must be non-blocking rights, and the application would automatically close any socket that becomes full, etc... etc... etc...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [message queue pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue), popular solutions are [rabbitMQ](http://rabbitmq.com) or Redis.

They all have python client !